# Add multiple columns and rows to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server, html-table

I am adding the first row and first column depending on the results I get from a query. This way the number of rows and number of columns is determined by the result of the query. This can vary with time. I want add the rest of the columns and rows and also want to use jQuery to add "class" to the other rows and columns of the table based on the class first row and the first column.

This is my current table:

```
<table class="numAlpha" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#ff9999"></th>
<th class="alpha a" bgcolor="#5588bb">a</th>
<th class="alpha b" bgcolor="#5588bb">b</th>
<th class="alpha c" bgcolor="#5588bb">c</th>
<th class="alpha d" bgcolor="#5588bb">d</th>
<th class="alpha e" bgcolor="#5588bb">e</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 1" bgcolor="#5588bb">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 2" bgcolor="#5588bb">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 3" bgcolor="#5588bb">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 4" bgcolor="#5588bb">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 5" bgcolor="#5588bb">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var alphas = [];
var num;

$('.exportBtn').click(function(event) {

$('.numAlpha th').each(function(i, el) {

    if($(el).attr('class'))
        alphas.push($(el).attr('class').slice(6));

 });

  $('.numAlpha td').each(function(i, el) {

   if($(el).attr('class')){
       num = $(el).attr('class').slice(4);
   }else{
       $(el).addClass(num + alphas[(i-1)]);
   }

   });
   });
```

I want my table to look like this:

```
  <table class="numAlpha" border="1">
  <tr>
  <th bgcolor="#ff9999"></th>
  <th class="alpha a" bgcolor="#5588bb">a</th>
  <th class="alpha b" bgcolor="#5588bb">b</th>
  <th class="alpha c" bgcolor="#5588bb">c</th>
  <th class="alpha d" bgcolor="#5588bb">d</th>
  <th class="alpha e" bgcolor="#5588bb">e</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="num 1" bgcolor="#5588bb">1</td>
  <td class="1a"></td>
  <td class="1b"></td>
  <td class="1c"></td>
  <td class="1d"></td>
  <td class="1e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="num 2" bgcolor="#5588bb">2</td>
  <td class="2a"></td>
  <td class="2b"></td>
  <td class="2c"></td>
  <td class="2d"></td>
  <td class="2e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="num 3" bgcolor="#5588bb">3</td>
  <td class="3a"></td>
  <td class="3b"></td>
  <td class="3c"></td>
  <td class="3d"></td>
  <td class="3e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="num 4" bgcolor="#5588bb">4</td>
  <td class="4a"></td>
  <td class="4b"></td>
  <td class="4c"></td>
  <td class="4d"></td>
  <td class="4e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="num 5" bgcolor="#5588bb">5</td>
  <td class="5a"></td>
  <td class="5b"></td>
  <td class="5c"></td>
  <td class="5d"></td>
  <td class="5e"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

in this case I need to add 5rowsx5columns give them the class with their corresponding first row and columns? Any idea how I can do all this with jQuery?

Now my table looks like so:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rashmee_p/qo3kok00/3/)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please edit your question so as to include the code you have already tried, and an explanation of how it is not working.

Comment: You haven't attempted to do anything. That's just HTML. Loop over `tableRowElement[elementNumber].insertCell(cellNumber)`.

Comment: @MJH I have added some jquery but I am not able to get it to work which is why i wanted a fresh perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Optimized @ehsan code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("tr td[bgcolor]").each(function(){
       var row = $(this).text();
     for(var i = 1; i < $("th").length; i++ )
       {
         var classTxt = row+$("th").eq(i).text();
           $(this).closest("tr").append("<td class=" + classTxt + ">"+ classTxt +"</td>");
         }
   })
})
```

```html
<table class="numAlpha" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#ff9999"></th>
<th class="alpha a" bgcolor="#5588bb">a</th>
<th class="alpha b" bgcolor="#5588bb">b</th>
<th class="alpha c" bgcolor="#5588bb">c</th>
<th class="alpha d" bgcolor="#5588bb">d</th>
<th class="alpha e" bgcolor="#5588bb">e</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 1" bgcolor="#5588bb">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 2" bgcolor="#5588bb">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 3" bgcolor="#5588bb">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 4" bgcolor="#5588bb">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 5" bgcolor="#5588bb">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**I put class Name in tag td,you can remove it.**

Change :

```
$(this).closest("tr").append("<td class=" + num+arr[i] + ">"+num+arr[i]+"</td>");
```

To :

```
 $(this).closest("tr").append("<td class=" + num+arr[i] + "></td>");
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
    
   $("tr td[bgcolor]").each(function(){
       
       var num = $(this).text();

       
       for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++ )
           $(this).closest("tr").append("<td class=" + num+arr[i] + ">"+num+arr[i]+"</td>");
       
   })
    
    
})
```

```html
    <table class="numAlpha" border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#ff9999"></th>
<th class="alpha a" bgcolor="#5588bb">a</th>
<th class="alpha b" bgcolor="#5588bb">b</th>
<th class="alpha c" bgcolor="#5588bb">c</th>
<th class="alpha d" bgcolor="#5588bb">d</th>
<th class="alpha e" bgcolor="#5588bb">e</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 1" bgcolor="#5588bb">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 2" bgcolor="#5588bb">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 3" bgcolor="#5588bb">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 4" bgcolor="#5588bb">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="num 5" bgcolor="#5588bb">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```